# Azure automation runbook error with Sharepoint CSOM assemblies

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of a Sharepoint list with the following script in local :

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
   
#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://..."
$ListName = "..."

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred= Get-Credential

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials

#Get list by title
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

...
```

The script works correctly and I get a return in my List variable.

Here is the script adapted for execution via runbook :

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Modules\User\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Modules\User\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://..."
$ListName = "..."
$CredObject = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "..."

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($CredObject.Username, $CredObject.Password)

#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials

#Get list by title
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

...
```

I get the following error : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

The command $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName) fails to retrieve list.

Have you ever encountered this problem and do you have a solution ?

I tried several things(Context.load, Context.ExecuteQuery, ...) but nothing works so far.